# Excel VBA - Color text in a cell if any cell text in a range is colored

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a function that counts red text cells in range.

```
Function CountRed(rngToSearch) As Long

Dim rngCel As Range

For Each rngCel In rngToSearch
    If rngCel.Font.Colorindex = 3 Then
        CountRed = CountRed + 1
    End If
Next rngCel

End Function
```

I'm trying now to write another function that sums cells in a range, and if there's any cell in that range with text color red, then the result should also be in red color.

Here's what I got:

```
Function SumR(rngToSum) As Long

Dim rngCel As Range
Dim IsThereRed

IsThereRed = 0

For Each rngCel In rngToSum
    If rngCel.Font.Colorindex = 3 Then
        IsThereRed = 1
    End If
Next rngCel

SumR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(rngToSum))

If IsThereRed = 1 Then SumR.Font.Colorindex = 3

End Function
```

But I get an error. Is there a way that this could work with a function?

Comment: Could you add what error does it make ?

Comment: Invalid qualifier on `SumR.Font.Colorindex = 3`. But even without that code line, I get `#Value` error, so even `SumR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(rngToSum))` isn't OK.

Comment: because you are trying to apply methods of a range object to a long variable type.

Comment: So it isn't possible to change cell properties inside a function. That's what my question basically was about. Thanks

Comment: actually, i was wrong about that. you can change properties, but i think not assign values. (sorry, it's been a while).... the real problem in the code is trying to apply range methods to a long time. either way, you may be better off using excel's built-in conditional formatting feature

Answer (score 0):

To assign a font color your need to define a range to do so. In this case you could define a range where your result (SumR) will be shown in the sheet.

Let's say your result will be in the cell A10. You put your result first in that cell and then color the font as needed:

```
With Range("A10")
.Value2 = SumR
.Font.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
.NumberFormat = "#,##0" 'if you want to have a specific format for the number
End With
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I know in which cell is the result?

Comment: You define in what cell you want the result. The variable SumR is the value of your operation stored in memory. Then you need to assign that value to a cell.  That's why you need to write the instruction Range("A1"). value=SumR